# Writing the change in a $\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ function in terms of its mixed partial derivatives

Tags: multivariable-calculus

$f$ is defined in open set $S \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ and at all points in $S$ partial derivatives $D_{1}f$ and $D_{21}f$ exist. Suppose $Q \subset S$ is a closed rectangle with sides parallel to the coordinate axes with $(a,b)$ & $(a+h,b+k)$ as opposite vertices, $h,k \neq 0.$

Define $\Delta(f,Q) = f(a+h,b+k) - f(a+h,b) - f(a,b+k) + f(a,b).$

I am trying to prove $\exists(x,y)$ in the interior of $Q$ s.t. $\Delta(f,Q) = hk(D_{21}f)(x,y).$

The result reminds me of a sort of multivariate application of the Mean Value Theorem, but I am looking for some help to express this idea more formally in a proof.

Comment: This is exactly Theorem 9.40 of Rudin's *Principles of Mathematical Analysis*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general idea in multivariable differential calculus proofs is to convert the problem into one from single variable calculus. This normally involves some sort of parametrization. Here, consider the function $g(t) = f(t,b+k) - f(t,b)$. Then
\begin{align*}
\Delta (f,Q) &= g(a+h) - g(a) \\
&= h*g'(x) & \text{MVT} \\
&= h*(D_1f(x,b+k) - D_1f(x,b)) \\
&= hk*(D_{21}f)(x,y). & \text{MVT}
\end{align*}
I recommend drawing the rectangle and interpreting the steps of this proof geometrically.